# AWK comparing two variables that are strings

Tags: string, bash, awk

I want to get a user intput at the begining af the script (as an argument) and then compare it to a string using awk !
I'm using -v to add the variable into the awk command(by the way the input is STRING)
But for some reason it won't show the expected output !
And i know that the problem is on the variable that i inserted into the awk command , because if i put instead of the variable the string that i want to find, the specific one that i know that is inside the file , it will find it and print the result i want.
I will show you code !

```
awk -v x=$a -F '[:,]' ' { if ($1 == $a )  print $5 }' /etc/passwd
```

i have also tried:

```
awk -v x="$a" -F '[:,]' ' { if ($1 == "$a" )  print "$5" }' /etc/passwd
```

But nothing. I cannot find the solution. 
A clarification here. I have made the correct seperation and i know the file what it includes!

**And here an example that works without the variable**

```
awk -v x=$a -F '[:,]' ' { if ($1 == "psz" )  print $5 }' /etc/passwd
```

psz is the string that i have set before the awk command at the a variable ( a="psz" ) like that.
And it is what i know that is inside the /etc/passwd at the first field ($1) !!

Comment: Kindly go through the link mentioned in your thread now, you need to only fix the procedure that how to call shell variables in `awk` then you should be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use instead of this:

```
awk -v x=$a -F '[:,]' ' { if ($1 == $a )  print $5 }' /etc/passwd
```

this:

```
awk -v x=$a -F '[:,]' ' { if ($1 == x )  print $5 }' /etc/passwd
```

You define `x` as a variable and this should be used in `awk`

Comment: thanks 
Im very dumb lol

Comment: @Psz_13, no, you are not. Can happen with anyone :)